# FIWARE AuthZForce 5.4.1 is not installing

Tags: fiware, fiware-wilma, authzforce

I am trying to install FIWARE AuthZForce 5.4.1, following the [official documentation](http://authzforce-ce-fiware.readthedocs.io/en/release-5.4.1d/InstallationAndAdministrationGuide.html), but with no success because the Tomcat7 is not starting during the installation process as can be seen below.

```
(Reading database ... 40187 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack authzforce-ce-server-dist-5.4.1.deb ...
Unpacking authzforce-ce-server (5.4.1) over (5.4.1) ...
Setting up authzforce-ce-server (5.4.1) ...
 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7                                                                                                                                                                     
[fail] 
dpkg: error processing package authzforce-ce-server (--install):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 authzforce-ce-server
```

Is there another way to install AuthZForce? The documentation is very poor. Since the AuthZForce is not correctly installed, I am getting the well known "AZF domain not created for application" message, as stated below:

[Fiware AuthZForce error: "AZF domain not created for application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714175/fiware-authzforce-error-azf-domain-not-created-for-application)

[“AZF domain not created for application” AuthZforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513118/azf-domain-not-created-for-application-authzforce)

Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I was not notified of this question until someone assigned a ticket linking to this on FIWARE JIRA yesterday. Btw, why use tag `fiware-wilma`? Wilma is a different product from AuthzForce. Anyway, I strongly recommend you upgrade to the latest version (8.0.1) as we are not maintaining v5.4.1 anymore which was using Tomcat7/Java 7. We switched to Tomcat8/Java 8 since v6.x. If you have an issue again and want faster response, follow Support request instructions on our Github repo or use authzforce tag.

Comment: ... and documentation is here: http://authzforce-ce-fiware.readthedocs.io/en/release-8.0.0/.

Comment: @cdan , just because we didnt have a specific tag for "fiware-azf" and the main dev that used to answer about azf was the main dev that used to answer questions about wilma (alonso)...

Comment: @cdan , the tag `authzforce` is still not created! I just saw another question related to AzF but the user cannot use a specific tag because it was not created yet on stackoverflow. I would create, but I still cannot due to my pontuation...

Comment: I tried, but stackoverflow says I need 1500 reputation to create a new tag, which I don't have :-( If you know someone that does and would be willing to add authzforce tag to this question, let me know.

Comment: Thanks to David Brossard, we now have an authzforce tag!

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the latest version, as we are not maintaining v5.4.1 anymore which was using Tomcat7/Java 7. We switched to Tomcat8/Java 8 since v6.x. If you have an issue again and want faster response, follow Support request instructions on our Github repo. [Documentation](http://authzforce-ce-fiware.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is available as well.