# Domain not found: AZF domain not created for application

Tags: fiware, fiware-wilma

I got this error while trying to configure level 2 authentication using idm,pep-proxy and pdp.
I am using latest version of authzforce,idm,pep-proxy but this error still persists.

```
config.azf = {
  enabled: true,
  protocol: 'http',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8080,
  custom_policy: undefined // use undefined to default policy checks (HTTP verb + path).
};
```

part of config that is relevant.

As I understand idm connected with authzforce should auto create domains, but for some reason that is not case.

I have tried with different versions, read similar issues on stack but problem still persist.Any advice or maybe point what i am doing wrong would be really helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“AZF domain not created for application” AuthZforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513118/azf-domain-not-created-for-application-authzforce)

Comment: You can also take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714175/fiware-authzforce-error-azf-domain-not-created-for-application

Comment: I have checked them, they are for older versions. But even when i followed them point by point with exact same versions and all things failed to work.  I wanted to see if people tested it on latest versions etc.

Comment: @Dalton i have rechecked that posts and noticed that u had successfully created domain, and u mention that it was failing because u had no permissions created. I know it was prob long time but have u created permissions using api or idm ( localhost:8000) Thanks.

Comment: If I remember well, I created with the IdM user interface (horizon). Try it and tell what happens.

Comment: Issue persists either i am missing some part not sure this is really mistery for me.  I even try with latest versions, try to change that etc still same simply IDM is not communicating with Authz properly. Why not sure and im running out of ideas. But thanks for your response.

Comment: I think it would be good if you update your question with all steps you followed, in order someone can help you...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990969/error-failed-to-update-policies-in-access-control-ge?noredirect=1#comment89002277_50990969 I have open issue with more info, it seem problem is with IDM witch should auto create domain pep-proxy simply doing its job of checking for domains but none is there because IDM failed to create it.

Comment: Hey Dalton sorry i contact u like this i know u are active here i managed to run all, but in finding one issue so maybe u encounter it. When u create permission to get for example v2/entities/{id} is there way to make sure that pep-proxy do not read that id part but only v2/entities/. It make hard for me to create permission to get entity based on id each time pep check like v2/entities/Room1 and of course that there is no permission with that url.