# Fiware AuthZForce error: "AZF domain not created for application"

Tags: fiware, authz, fiware-wilma, pdp, authzforce

I'm trying to protect Orion Context Broker using KeyRock idm, Wilma PEP-Proxy and AuthZForce PDP over Docker. For now, level 1 security works well and I can deny access to non logged users, but I get this error on Wilma when trying to add level 2.

```
AZF domain not created for application <applicationID>
```

Here it is my azf configuration in Wilma's config.js file:

```
config.azf = {
    enabled: true,
    protocol: 'http',
    host: 'azfcontainer',
    port: 8080,
    custom_policy: undefined
};
```

And this is how I set the access control configuration on KeyRock:

```
# ACCESS CONTROL GE
ACCESS_CONTROL_URL = 'http://azfcontainer:8080'
ACCESS_CONTROL_MAGIC_KEY = None
```

I have created the custom policies on Keyrock, but AuthZForce logs don't show any request from KeyRock or Wilma, so no domain is created on the PDP. I have checked that all containers can see and reach each other and that all ports are up. I may be missing some configuration.

These are the versions I'm using:

```
keyrock=5.4.1
wilma=5.4
autzforce=6.0.0/5.4.1
```

This question is the same that [“AZF domain not created for application” AuthZforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513118/azf-domain-not-created-for-application-authzforce), but my problem persists even with the shown AuthZForce GE Configuration.

Comment: Which versions of KeyRock, Wilma and AuthzForce are you using?

Comment: I have edited the question with the versions I'm using. `keyrock=5.4.1`, `wilma=5.4` and `autzforce=6.0.0 and 5.4.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause of this problem that is present when the *AuthZForce **is not** behind a PEP Proxy* and therefore the variable ACCESS_CONTROL_MAGIC_KEY is not modified (None by default).

It seems horizon reads both ACCESS_CONTROL_URL and ACCESS_CONTROL_MAGIC_KEY parameters in **openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py** when it needs to connect to AuthZForce. Theoretically, the second parameter is optional (it introduces a 'X-Auth-Token' header for the PEP Proxy), but if horizon detects it is None (the default value in local_settings.py) or an empty string, the log shows a Warning and returns inmediatly from the function "policyset_update" in **openstack_dashboard/fiware_api/access_control_ge.py**. So the communication to AuthZForce never takes place.

The easier way to solve the problem is to write some text as magic key in: **openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py**:

```py
# ACCESS CONTROL GE
ACCESS_CONTROL_URL = 'http://authzforce_url:port'
ACCESS_CONTROL_MAGIC_KEY = '1234567890' # DO NOT LEAVE None OR EMPTY
```

Thus, a 'X-Auth-Token' header will be generated, but it shouldn't affect to the communication when the AuthZForce isn't behind a PEP Proxy (the header is simply ignored).

**Notice:** Remember to delete the cached bytecode file "openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py**c**" when making changes to assure the new config is updated after restart horizon service.

**PS:** I sent a pull request to https://github.com/ging/horizon with a simple modification that fixes the problem.

Comment: Hello. I did what you told, in local_settings.py, but I am also getting the "AZF domain not created for application629cd23fe9bb42c..." message. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Are you able to connect to your AuthZForce REST API?

Comment: It is working now. I am not sure, but I think the problem was because I had not created the permission before. Or something like that. Thanks.