# What does the magic key do in Wilma and AZF?

Tags: authorization, fiware, role-base-authorization, fiware-wilma

I would like to know the real use of the magic key parameter at Wilma PEP Proxy as well in the AZF. Is this mandatory in both configuration? If not, when do we need to use it?

I saw that there is bug related to [it described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714175/fiware-authzforce-error-azf-domain-not-created-for-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MagicKey is used to enable a permanent valid token in Wilma. For instance, if you set MagicKey parameter to `foo`, then every received request with `X-Auth-Token:foo` will be automatically redirected, without validation with Keyrock.